# Is "willingness" dependent upon desire?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

For instance can I be willing to do something even if I don't want to do it?

If I'm willing but not exactly "eager", can I still claim "willingness" or is it just compliance?

Is desire a prerequisite for willingness?

Comment: "Willingness" is relative, not absolute.  You may be more or less willing to do something.  Like you may be willing to loan your ne'er-do-well brother-in-law some money, to keep peace in the family, even though you don't want to.

Answer (score 1):

"Willingness" can be as little as acquiesced agreement.  One can reluct to do something, abhor everything about it, be completely disgusted at having to do it, but still do it "willingly" under the circumstances of duress, coercion, servitude, etc., which can all be a far cry short of desire or wanting to do it.

This isn't to say that "willingness" isn't ever more than consent, that it can't be eager.  At the same time, don't confuse "willingness" with "willfulness" or the expression of "will" (personal drive).

Comment: This is a great answer.  The word often goes hand-in-hand with hesitation, such as *It took convincing, but Bob is willing to go along with it.*

Comment: @user1717828 : When it came down to the choice of dying or having his leg cut off with a rusty knife and not even a shot of whiskey right there in the mud and the filth and the din of war, Sarge was willing to let Doc Cotton start hacking away, but as he bit down on that bullet and the sawing started and his screams seemed to fill the air for miles, I do believe it an honest assessment to say that he didn't want to do it.  The only thing in all of creation he wanted less was the grave, and on that point, I think he might well have been reconsidering his position.